# How to change look and feel of swing application in intellij idea

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, look-and-feel

I am a student, I am using idea for my applications. 
I am working on swing form , I have done every thing but unable to change look and feel of my app.

I am using intellij idea community edition, can anyone tell me how I can change look and feel of my swing application?

Comment: This is just a suggestion and is also personal preference, but I love flat colored UI's. I've been noticing that a lot of developers nowadays are styling their programs with flat colors. It gives them a more simplistic and modern look in my opinion. If you're interested, I would suggest using https://flatuicolors.com/ they have a decent amount of colors to use. I personally use them in my java applications.

Comment: Swing is ok... i recommend to use **JavaFx**. it helps in making better applications than swing. It supports css files. or you can make a hybirid of swing and javafx [try this for starters](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCub7wu5XOAhUOTI8KHfjFDoEQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.javafxtutorials.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEEeaC3b1MT9CnHnwaDtE1siaBQEQ&sig2=o1liIGGuJ-YkYo8_cA-S3ghttp://)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change look and feel in Java just add this to your main method before you create the GUI.

```java
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");  // Windows Look and feel
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```